# Setting button background drawable in different class

Tags: android, button, android-activity, background, drawable

I am working on a game for Android and am having a little bit of trouble figuring this out.

I have a main activity and I have a GameView (SurfaceView). I want to change the background image of a button in the MainActivity when an action is taken in GameView.

My MainActivity is an Activity bu the GameView is not an Activity, it is just being called and displayed inside of my MainActivity.

I thought about doing the following:

Main Activity:

```
public void setNumberLivesPicture(final Drawable background){
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {     
            public void run() {         
                numberLivesPicture.setBackgroundDrawable(background);     
            } 
         });
    }
```

GameView:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView{

    int difficulty =  HomePage.getDifficulty();
    int player = HomePage.getPlayer();
    String direction =  MainActivity.getDirection();
    boolean audio = HomePage.getAudio();
    private Drawable bloodspatterdead;
    Button numberLivesPicture;
    Button numberLivesButton;
    MainActivity mAct;


    public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, MainActivity MActivity, Button NumberLives) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this);
        if (audio == true){
            backgroundNoise.start();
        }       
        getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback()
        {

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                boolean retry = true;
                GameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
                while (retry) {
                    try {
                        gameLoopThread.join();
                        retry = false;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                }
            }           

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                createSprites(difficulty);
                GameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
                gameLoopThread.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                    int width, int height) {
            }
        });
    }


    private void checkForEnemyCollision() {

        int x = playerSprite.getPlayerX();
        int y = playerSprite.getPlayerY();

        Rect playerRect = new Rect(x, y, (x + playerSprite.getPlayerWidth()), (y + playerSprite.getPlayerHeight()));
        for (int i = 0; i<sprites.size(); i++)
        {
            Rect zombieSprite = sprites.get(i).getZombieBounds();
            if(zombieSprite.intersect(playerRect))
            {           
       if (justDied == true){         // if you just died, we'll give you a break
                }

                if (justDied == false){

    if (NumberOfLives <= 1){   // if you do not have any extra lives.. you die!

                        if (shieldsActivated >= 1){
                            shieldsActivated--;
                            if (audio == true){
                                shielddestroyed.start();
                            }
                        }

                        if (shieldsActivated == 0)
                        {           

((MainActivity) getContext()).setTextView("THE ZOMBIES ATE YOUR BRAINS!!");

                        if (audio == true){
                            backgroundNoise.stop();
                            youaredeadmessage.start();              
                            }

                        for (int z = 0; z<playerSprites.size(); z++)
                        {
                        playerSprites.remove(z);
                        }
                        alive = false;

                    }
                    }
                    if (NumberOfLives > 1){

                        if (shieldsActivated >= 1){
                            shieldsActivated--;
                            if (audio == true){
                                shielddestroyed.start();
                            }
                        }

                        else if (shieldsActivated == 1){
                            shieldsActivated=0;
                            if (audio == true)
                            {
                                shielddestroyed.start();
                            }
                        }

else if (shieldsActivated == 0){                        
NumberOfLives = NumberOfLives -1;
justDied = true;

if (NumberOfLives == 4){

//Button numberOfLives2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.numberLivesPicture);
numberLivesPicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.numberLivesPicture);

((MainActivity) getContext()).setNumberLivesPicture(R.id.numberLivesPicture);                           numberLivesPicture.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.numberlives4);
                                }
```

But this did not work :(

EDIT:

I have used this with much success for changing TEXT inside of a TextView but am not sure how I can use a method like this to change backgrounds:

```
public void setTextView(final String txt){
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {     
            public void run() {         
                txv.setText(txt);     
            } 
         });
    }
```

Used with:

```
((MainActivity) getContext()).setTextView("THE ZOMBIES ATE YOUR BRAINS!!");
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: your surface view is on main activity or on different activity.

Comment: my SurfaceView is not inside my MainActivity, but is not an activity on it's own. My MainActivity calls the SurfaceView and places it inside (this acts as my game surface). So you can treat it as a different activity

Comment: Ok what you can do is you can send broadcast to your main activity from surfaceview and you can simply update your data in main activity.

Comment: I don't think this will work as my MainActivity is my game itself so for me to have to refresh this after every second (when the change could occur) would be a little much.

I edited the comment to show how I am changing the text and this works very well for me but not sure how I can use this for background or images.

Comment: The suggestion I am giving you is a very generic suggestion. Anyway I will try to find out problem in your code.

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you way using Object Oriented Methodology. Bring Button reference from Activity to surfaceView class and then Use runUiThread to update background of Button on any condition

```
public class SurFaceViewClass extends SurfaceView {

Button btnButton;
MainActivity mAct;

public SurFaceViewClass(MainActivity mact, Button btn) {
    super(mact);
    mAct = mact;
    btnButton = btn;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    // if(yourconnditIOn)
    mAct.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            btnButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }
    });
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
}
```

runOnUiThread is necessary as SurfaceView run in its own thread. Now see how you will call it in Activity

```
    SurFaceViewClass msClass=new SurFaceViewClass(this, yourbttn);
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure how I would call this in my activity to be constantly checking for / updating it? Also - it is not a TouchEvent that would be triggering it.

Comment: Take handler to check constantly, But not  you have instance of button   so you can change background anytime, that's important

Comment: I have updated my main post to show part of my GameView. Would it work in combination with this? I have tried what you have suggested but no luck.

Comment: No you did not implement my solution. Bring Button instance and update it. If you have single activity for it and bringing instance of activity will do the trick

Comment: I am afraid I don't quite understand. My button I am trying to update is located in my MainActivity.

Comment: Use object oriented concept dude, if you have an object of any class, you can access and change it

Answer (score 1):

There can be several possible ways. You can use broadcast sender and receiver for you case.

Steps mentioned below:

Step 1: Create a broadcast receiver in your main activity to receive broadcast from your surfaceview.

BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("update_button")) {
            // UPDATE YOUR BUTTON HERE.
        }
    }
};
```

Step 2: Register your receiver after creating your broadcast receiver in main activity.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("update_button");
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Step 3: Send broadcast from your surface view to update button.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("update_button");
// HERE YOU CAN PUT EXTRAS IN  YOUR INTENT
SendBroadcast(intent);
```

Wherever you have registered your broadcast receiver it will automatically receive broadcast and update your button in main activity. Using above approach you can update your button or any data from any class.

Comment: So within my SendBroadcast how exactly would I tell it to change the background to @drawable/image2 for example? Not entirely sure how extras work.

Comment: In that same way. You can putExtra if you want to send some data in main activity to update button. If you can get data in main activity itself then you can update it their. Just write numberLivesPicture.setBackgroundDrawable(background); in onReceive to update your button backgroud and check.

Comment: do you have your drawable in resources also you can try btn.setBackgroundResource to set image.

Comment: instead of using Receiver, Just use my solution

Comment: yes the drawable is in my resources.          numberOfLives.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.numberlives4); comes back with a NullPointerException on that line when the condition is met.

Comment: can you check number numberOfLives is null or not. I think numberOfLives is null at that point. Also check nuberlives4.

Comment: Sorry - it is returning a NPE when the condition is met (NumberOfLives == 4) in my case. I can initialize my button with numberlives4 drawable perfectly fine.

Comment: numberOfLives.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.numberlives4); There are only two objects which can be null numberOfLives and numberlives4. You are already saying that numberoflives4 is not null then numberOfLives is null. So I think now you can solve your problem its a null pointer exception you are getting because any of you object is null.

Comment: sorry, I meant that NumberOfLives was not null, it is possible that numberOfLives is null (sorry for the very close naming). Why would it be that numberOfLives would be null? Can I not call on MainActivity's buttons from GameView?

Comment: First you check you are creating GameView before assinging of or after of numberOfLives.

Comment: can you post onCreate(where you are creating GameView and assinging object to numberOfLives) of your main activity.

Comment: I have created GameView before declaring numberOfLives

Comment: ok create it after and try. one more thing is setContentView you need to call before creating GameView. so can you try following sequence. 1. Setcontentview 2. assign button 3. create GameView

Comment: Did not seem to work, I am not setting ContentView inside my GameView but Context.

I will try and figure this out. Thank you for everything I will not waste your time.

Comment: I mean to say is setContentView in your main activity. After that Button numberOfLives = (Button) findViewById(R.id.numberLivesPicture); then create your GameView. Ok you try it and comment how you fix.

Comment: But how would it work with putting: Button numberOfLives = (Button) findViewById(R.id.numberLivesPicture); inside my Main Activity? I have to re-initialize it in GameView like I did don't I?